# special android media player with special extension

Tags: android, media-player

I have android application which read mp3 files from SD, but for keep my mp3 files not shown to the      public in "Music" I changed the extension of them to ".kha", after that I modified my code to find them by filter like that

```
class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".kha") || name.endsWith(".KHA"));
    }
}
```

It's working in good way, but some devices are not able to read this extension 
Is there any way to force or to make the player does not care about the extension ?

Comment: Please mention the circumstances (we need more info)

Comment: I mean that I want to play file myFile.kha without looking to the extension which was mp3 in real

Answer (score 0):

Change the names of the files, you can make a **prefix** of these files.

**Ex:**

media_firstfile.anything

media_secondfile.anything

then you can filter all files starting with prefix "**media_**" without care of files extensions.

Comment: I did that but the problem is not to find the files or not, Its about the default media player of the device, some players can not play them as the fake extension

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: as you wrote ".anything"